# Laravel 5.3 belongsToMany return null, pivot data

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have a next models:

```
class Product extends Model{
    protected $table = 'products';

    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Payment', 'payment_product', 'product_id', 'payment_id')
    }
}

class Payment extends Model{
    protected $table = 'payments';

    public function products(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

Pivot table: payment_product(id, product_id, payment_id)

Eloquent

```
 public function details($id){
        $product = Product::with('payments')->find($id);
        dd($product->payments); // return null
        return view('products.details', ['product' => $product]);
    }
```

I need to bring in a foreach, but $product->payments is null. Why is that ?
All the tables are not empty.

**UPD**
Sub query $this->belongsToMany('App\Payment', 'payment_product', 'product_id', 'payment_id');
Results:

[image]

Comment: Just an FYI, because you're following laravel's naming convention you don't have to provide the table names/columns in your relationships.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
public function payments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Payment', 'payment_product', 'payment_id', 'product_id')
}
```

I think you have your FK in the wrong order.

In fact, I don't think you need to specify anything more than:

```
public function payments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Payment')
}
```

Comment: I tried,  public function payments(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Payment');
    }
Don't work

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are joining two tables based on unrelated fields.

When you do

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Payment', 'payment_product', 'product_id', 'payment_id')
```

your table `products` gets inner joined with `payment_product` on
`products.product_id = payment_product.payment_id`. 
But I think these two columns are not the related keys. Instead, in your `payment_product`, join with the `product_id` in this table with products.product_id. 
That might work.

Comment: Model Payment and Product has protected $primaryKey = 'id';
$product = Product::with('payments')->find($id);
dd($product->relationsToArray(););

array:1 [▼
  "payments" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:7 [▶]
    1 => array:7 [▶]
  ]
]

That good. But foreach($product->payment as $payment){...}, error: invalid argument supplied for foreach

Comment: the query is not returning any results. run the same raw sql command in mysql terminal and see if you are getting results there. if not, you are probably joining wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Rename payments to payments_method:

```
public function payments_method(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Payment'); //or ('App\Payment', 'payment_product', 'payment_id', 'product_id') 
}

 $product = Product::find($id);
 $product->payments_method; //this is work
```

This is magic:)